# Import & Export Django Package Foreign Key CSV File Import Issue

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I'm trying to import scores for student data and I keep getting the error message that the query doesn't match on the import. I tried designating the import to look at the state_province field as the foreign key, but I don't think I have it written correctly. Secondly for some reason on my date field keeps failing the null constraint which I'm not understanding why since the excel file data is in the correct format. I set in the model null=true for now to bypass.Here is my code. I appreciate the help. Thank you

```
STUDENT MODEL

class Student(models.Model):
    studentpsid= models.CharField(primary_key = True , default = "", max_length = 50, unique = True)
    student_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, default = "")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 50,default = "")
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 1,default = "")
    birth_date = models.DateField(blank= True)
    student_grade = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = "")
    home_room = models.CharField(max_length = 5, default = "")
    student_enrollment = models.CharField(max_length = 2, default = "")
    school_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15, default = "") 
    email = models.EmailField(default = "")
    projected_graduation_year = models.CharField(max_length = 4, default = "")
    counseling_goal = models.TextField(max_length = 500, blank = True)
    win_username = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    win_password = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank=True)
    offsite_laptop = models.BooleanField(default = False, blank = True)
    state_province = models.CharField(max_length = 50, unique=True,null=True,blank = True , default = None)
    lunch_balance = models.FloatField(blank = True, default = 0)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 1, blank = True)
    alert_medical = models.TextField(max_length = 500, blank =True)
    district_code = models.ForeignKey(NJDistictCodes,on_delete = models.PROTECT, blank = True, default = 0)
    image = models.ImageField(default ="default.png", upload_to ='student_pics') 
 
    class Meta:
       verbose_name_plural = "Student"
    def __str__(self):
        return self.student_name     

TEST SCORE MODEL

class MindPrint(models.Model):
     state_province = models.ForeignKey(Student, to_field="state_province" ,on_delete = models.CASCADE, default = None,null=True,blank = True) 
     test_date = models.DateField(null=True)
     reasoning_verbal = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     reasoning_spatial = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     reasoning_abstract = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     executive_flexibility = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     executive_working_memory = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     executive_attention = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     speed_processing = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     speed_visual_motor = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     memory_verbal = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)
     memory_visual = models.CharField(max_length = 1, default = 0, blank = True)

     class Meta:
             verbose_name_plural = "Mind Print"
    
     def __str__(self):
        return str(self.state_province)
```

Here are my Admin.py file settings.

```
from inspect import Attribute
from django.contrib import admin
from import_export.admin import ImportExportActionModelAdmin
from import_export import resources, fields
from import_export.widgets import ForeignKeyWidget
from .models import Student, MindPrint

class MindPrintResource (resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
      model = MindPrint
      import_id_fields = ('state_province',)
      state_province = fields.Field(column_name='state_province', attribute='state_province',widget=ForeignKeyWidget(Student, 'state_province'))
      fields = ('state_province','test_date','reasoning_verbal','reasoning_spatial','reasoning_abstract','executive_flexibility','executive_working_memory',
      'executive_attention','speed_processing','speed_visual_motor','memory_verbal','memory_visual')  
     

class MindPrintAdmin (ImportExportActionModelAdmin):   
     resource_class = MindPrintResource
     list_display = ('state_province_id','student_name','test_date','reasoning_verbal','reasoning_spatial','reasoning_abstract','executive_flexibility','executive_working_memory',
     'executive_attention','speed_processing','speed_visual_motor','memory_verbal','memory_visual') 

     def student_name(self,obj):
           return obj.state_province.student_name

admin.site.register(MindPrint,MindPrintAdmin)
```

Here is a screenshot of the error on import.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have configured an import of a `MindPrint` model object.  When you import the source data file, it expects there to be a field called `state_province` which is a FK reference to the `Student` model.  Since this is an FK relationship, the import process expects that this reference exists.  In your case, the `Student` resource with `state_province` of `1234567899` does not exist, and therefore you see the `Student.DoesNotExist` error.

There are [several API hooks](https://django-import-export.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_resources.html) you can use to check for missing `Student` rows, and create them if they don't exist.  Or you can override `ForeignKeyWidget` to create the resource before lookup.

Comment: But within the student table, there is a student in the table with that test number. So it does exist. Am I mapping this incorrectly?